# BackgroundImageView should Animate

Tags: uitableview, swift, animation, background-image

I want to fade in an UIImageView as a BackgroundView of an UITableView. It's not animating. The image is just there. Any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "theImage")
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = backgroundImage
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView

    //Tried it this way
    imageView.alpha = 0.0

    //and that way
    self.tableView.backgroundView?.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        //Both not animating
        self.tableView.backgroundView?.alpha = 1.0
        imageView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you call it in `viewWillAppear` it happens before the view is loaded so the animation is invisible.
Try change it to `viewDidAppear` and it will work. You don't need to change

```
self.tableView.backgroundView?.alpha = 0.0
```

`imageView.alpha` is enough, try that:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "theImage")
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = backgroundImage
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView

        imageView.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            imageView.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
```

Comment: Nope, that's not working. Same behaviour as before. It works when I put the code in viewDidLoad and that's good enough for me in this case. Thanks anyway

Comment: @NickSt I tried and it definitely works. Did you copy and paste my code? viewDidAppear fires after viewDidLoad so is should work in viewDidAppear too.

Comment: Yes, I did. I even tried to load the image in viewDidLoad and the animations code in viewDidAppear. That didn't work as well.